# AssertionError "assert schema is not None" when trying to write dataframe to local MySQL database using to_sql()

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, etl

I have about 2M rows of data in a dataframe and want to write this data to a table (already created code earlier in execution) `EXPENDITURES`.  I am using `to_sql()` but am getting this error.  Below is also the code.

```
in has_table
    assert schema is not None
AssertionError
```

```py
def load_ce_expenditures(df_datasource_table, tbl):

    logger.info('Start Load Session - Consumer Expenditures - Expenditures Table')
    #logger.info("Loading dataframe %s into table %s", df_datasource_table.name, tbl.name)

    try:
        # Connect to local MySQL database
        start1 = time.time()
        #conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        #    host="localhost",
        #    user="root",
        #    password="1234",
        #    database="ConsumerExpenditures10")
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="1234",
            database=dbName)

        database_uri = 'mysql+pymysql://root:1234@localhost:3306'
        localEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_uri)

        end1 = time.time() - start1
        logger.info("Connect to local database : {} seconds".format(end1))

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Now we will load the data in the dataframe into the EXPENDITURES table
        # First, check if EXPENDITURES table is filled
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `EXPENDITURES`"
        query_result = cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result[0] < 851342:

            # Bulk insert dataframe rows from EXPENDITURES csv file into local MySQL EXPENDITURES table
            start1 = time.time()
            df_datasource_table.to_sql(con=localEngine, name="EXPENDITURES", if_exists="replace", chunksize=50000)
            end1 = time.time() - start1
            logger.info("Inserting EXPENDITURES records took : {} seconds".format(end1))

    except:
        # printing stack trace
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Here is the code where I create the database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EXPENDITURES (EXPENDITURE_ID varchar(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    HOUSEHOLD_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                    YEAR INT(11) NOT NULL,
                    MONTH INT(11) NOT NULL, 
                    PRODUCT_CODE VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
                    COST DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                    GIFT INT(11) NOT NULL,
                    IS_TRAINING INT(255) NOT NULL,
                    INDEX NAME(HOUSEHOLD_ID))
                """))
```

Here is the code where I create the database:

```py
result = conn_local.execute(text("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(dbName)))
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.  If the schema is not specified in `to_sql()` then it should automatically just pick the default schema.  Are there permissions I need to set for the schema when the `EXPENDITURES` table is created?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def load_ce_expenditures(df_datasource_table, tbl):

    logger.info('Start Load Session - Consumer Expenditures - Expenditures Table')
    #logger.info("Loading dataframe %s into table %s", df_datasource_table.name, tbl.name)

    try:
        # Connect to local MySQL database
        start1 = time.time()
        conn = MySQLConnection()
        conn.connect(user="username", password="password", host=REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS, 
             database="test_db")

        database_uri = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@{REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS}:3306/test_db"
        localEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_uri)

        end1 = time.time() - start1
        logger.info("Connect to local database : {} seconds".format(end1))

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Now we will load the data in the dataframe into the EXPENDITURES table
        # First, check if EXPENDITURES table is filled
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `EXPENDITURES`"
        query_result = cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result[0] < 851342:

            # Bulk insert dataframe rows from EXPENDITURES csv file into local MySQL EXPENDITURES table
            start1 = time.time()
            df_datasource_table.to_sql(con=localEngine, name="test_db.expenditures", if_exists="replace", chunksize=50000)
            end1 = time.time() - start1
            logger.info("Inserting EXPENDITURES records took : {} seconds".format(end1))

    except:
        # printing stack trace
        traceback.print_exc()


data = {
    "calories": [420, 380, 390],
    "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

load_ce_expenditures(pd.DataFrame(data), "test")
```

Comment: how long did it take?  I wonder if my laptop is just slow?  how big is this database you have?

Comment: Not long, I created the database with the SQL you provided, so the database was empty.  But it ran without error.